# Best Practice CleanUp ViewModelLocator

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

ViewModel in my MVVM Light application has some resourse, that must be dispose when application is closing. I have CleanUp method in ViewModelLocator to do it. Where is right place in my application to call CleanUp method.

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewModelLocator class.
    /// </summary>
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }
    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }
    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        var main=SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        main.Dispose();
    }
}
public class MainViewModel:ViewModelBase, IDisposable
{

    public void Dispose()
    {
       disposableResoure.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Closing` or `Closed` event on the `MainWindow` class of the `Application` class - probably best use the `Closed` event because the window will no longer be visible.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow(v=vs.110).aspx

Or you could use the `Exit` event on the `Application` class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.exit(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're exiting the application, then why clean up resources at all?  The OS will do that when the process is torn down.  You want to call `Dispose()` on an `IDisposable` when you no longer need the resource so you can clean up all the unmanaged resources.  If the process is getting tossed out, then there isn't a need to call it since garbage collection isn't going to happen in the memory space after the process is gone.

I agree that Disposing of resources after your Window has gone out of "scope" to the user and is no longer needed, but the end of the process is not necessary.

[Here](https://galasoft.ch/posts/2010/03/whats-new-in-mvvm-light-v3/) is another way to use the `Cleanup()` method: